# jq: how to add double quotes for string values

Tags: jq

given this JSON:

```json
{
  "stringKey": "this is a string",
  "numberKey": 1234,
  "jsonKey": [
    {"numberKey": 1, "stringKey": "0x" }
  ]
}
```

and this jq expression

```bash
to_entries|map("export let " + .key + " = " + (.value | tostring)) | .[]
```

I get this:

```
export let stringKey = this is a string
export let numberKey = 1234
export let jsonKey = [{"numberKey":1,"stringKey":"0x"}]
```

however I want this (note double quotes around `this is a string`):

```
export let stringKey = "this is a string"
export let numberKey = 1234
export let jsonKey = [{"numberKey":1,"stringKey":"0x"}]
```

jqplay snippet can be found https://jqplay.org/s/MYdILy4Xfw3

any help? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a JSON-encoded output, use `tojson` instead of `tostring`:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "export let " + .key + " = " + (.value | tojson)'
```

```bash
export let stringKey = "this is a string"
export let numberKey = 1234
export let jsonKey = [{"numberKey":1,"stringKey":"0x"}]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7x8BoChyoNx)

---

With the same effect, you can also use the `@json` syntax and provide the value through string interpolation:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "export let " + .key + @json " = \(.value)"'
```

```bash
export let stringKey = "this is a string"
export let numberKey = 1234
export let jsonKey = [{"numberKey":1,"stringKey":"0x"}]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gK7cAcAg-_F)

---

Note: For simplicity, I have also turned `map(…) | .[]` into `.[] | …`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`tojson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Convertto/fromJSON), not `tostring`. It does exactly what you need for all data types.

```
to_entries|map("export let " + .key + " = " + (.value | tojson)) | .[]
```

Check it [online](https://jqplay.org/s/cvA8BiByhPq).